# Where to put Angular PWA update service?

Tags: angular, service, progressive-web-apps, swupdate

I've got a PWA app running and wanted to declutter the application.component.
So I created this self-contained service to watch for PWA updates and notify the user:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material/snack-bar";

import { SwUpdate } from "@angular/service-worker";
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PwaUpdatesService {

  constructor(
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private _swUpdate: SwUpdate,
  ) {

    if (environment.production) {
      this.setupUpdates();
    }
  }

  setupUpdates() {
    this._swUpdate.available.subscribe(u => {
      this._swUpdate.activateUpdate().then(e => {
        this._snackBar.open("There is an update", "reload app", { duration: 99999 }).onAction().subscribe(
          () => location.reload()
        );
      });
    });

    const everySixHours$ = interval(6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    everySixHours$.subscribe(() => this._swUpdate.checkForUpdate());
  }

}
```

My question is, where do I 'call' this service so it will get created and run on app startup?
I tried to put it into the app.module providers' section, but it won't get created.

I could import the service again in the app.component, but I wanted to declutter that one. So where do I put an auto-running service?

[Update]
I tried to import it in my app.component, but the notifications won't fire. Does it seem the service will be destroyed after calling them?

```
constructor(
  private pwaUpdatesService: PwaUpdatesService,
) {
    pwaUpdatesService.setupUpdates();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call it inside of `app.component.ts`, which is the root component in most cases

```
constructor(private readonly _pwaService: PwaUpdatesService){
  this._pwaService.setupUpdates();
}
```

Comment: `setupUpdates()` gets called, but I get not update notification. It seems the service has been stopped.

Comment: @Sam The update mechanism is another thing entirely, the service does not "stop" though. I recommend debugging to see if the callback of the `subscribe()` is even reached. You can then go from there and find the issue.

Comment: Yep, I tried several times: If I put `this._swUpdate.available.subscribe` in the app.component it works, when I move it to the service and call the service from the app.component it does not work anymore.
finicky thing it is!